# Oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver() does not exist error

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

i am trying to execute a sql command from a java program..i dont have any errors regarding this code..but i am facing connection refusals from the database..

```
import java.sql.*;
public class DBCreateTable
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        DriverManager.registerDriver (new Oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(
              "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","lms","abc");
        Statement stmt=con.CreateStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate("create table emp(eno number(5),name varchar2(20))");
    }
}
```

the errors encountered are:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Connection refused(DESCRIPTION=(TMP=)(VSNNUM=185599488)(ERR=12505)(ERROR_STACK=(ERROR=(CODE=12505)(EMFI=4))))
        at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
        at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:179)
        at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:333)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection.<init>(OracleConnection.java:404)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.getConnectionInstance(OracleDriver.ja
va:468)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:314)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
        at DBCreateTable.main(DBCreateTable.java:7)
```

In my sql commands i have done the following..

```
    SQL> connect system/tiger;
    SQL> create user lms identified by abc;
    SQL> grant connect,resource to lms;
```

and plz tell me what is scott tiger..i am messing a lot there..what users are there..what to unlock and how?? plz thanks..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add an oracle driver jar to the project build path, and it should work.
(eg. http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven/mule/dependencies/maven1/oracle-jdbc/jars/ojdbc14.jar)

Comment: The link moved: http://maven.ibiblio.org/maven/mule/dependencies/oracle/ojdbc14/9i/

Answer (score 0):

Your package name is wrong.

```
DriverManager.registerDriver (new **Oracle**.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
```

In java, package name always start by uncapitalize letter. Your program failed in `compilation time`.

Comment: yes i am still getting this error...DBCreateTable.java:6: error: package oracle.jdbc.driver does not exist
DriverManager.registerDriver (new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());

Comment: do you sure `oracle` jar file is in your application `class-path`.

Comment: hey doesnt oracle.jar file doesnt come in the jdk package?

Comment: No, `oracle.jar` is not part of the JDK. You must put the Oracle JDBC driver JAR in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

The oracle.jdbc.driver.* classes, theojdbc4.jar file, and theOracleConnectionCacheImpl class are no longer supported or available from Oracle 11g onwards. So use oracle.jdbc.oracledriver instead.

Answer (score -2):

karjala
did you dowload Oracle JDBC Drivers first download them, You can download Oracle JDBC drivers from here
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html 
Choose the version appropriate for your database version.

Java Program to Connect to Oracle:
The following Java program uses Oracle JDBC driver to connect to a running Oracle database instance. You can use this program on any Oracle database as this example uses Oracle’s built-in dummy table DUAL for fetching system date. DUAL enables us to get values such as system date using a normal SQL query.

1 // Example Java Program - Oracle Database Connectivity
2
 import java.sql.Connection;
3
 import java.sql.Date;
4
 import java.sql.DriverManager;
5
 import java.sql.ResultSet;
6
 import java.sql.SQLException;
7
 import java.sql.Statement;
8

9
public class OracleSample {
10

11
    public static final String DBURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE";
12
    public static final String DBUSER = "system";
13
    public static final String DBPASS = "manager";
14

15
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
16

17
        // Load Oracle JDBC Driver
18
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
19

20
        // Connect to Oracle Database
21
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DBURL, DBUSER, DBPASS);
22

23
        Statement statement = con.createStatement();
24

25
        // Execute a SELECT query on Oracle Dummy DUAL Table. Useful for           retrieving system values
26
        // Enables us to retrieve values as if querying from a table
27
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL");
28

29

30
        if (rs.next()) {
31
            Date currentDate = rs.getDate(1); // get first column returned
32
            System.out.println("Current Date from Oracle is : "+currentDate);
33
        }
34
        rs.close();
35
        statement.close();
36
        con.close();
37
    }
38
}

i hope this will help you guys....... :-)